# ggplot2 geom_path plot is very "fuzzy." How can I fix this?

Tags: r, ggplot2, blurry

I am seeing some very strange (and undesirable) behavior from ggplot.  I am using the following code to generate a plot with differently colored segments along a single path.

```
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)

testData = fread("test_data.tsv")

ggplot(testData, aes(X, Y, color = Color, group = 1)) +
  geom_path(size = 1.5) + scale_color_identity()
```

(The data within "test_data.tsv" can be found at [this pastebin](https://pastebin.com/raw/hP7sWiNn).)

The resulting plot looks like this:
[image: fuzzy plot]

As you can see, the edges are VERY fuzzy (or blurry, or jagged, or whatever you want to call them), and I can't seem to fix them.  I've tried exporting at a higher dpi, or in other graphics formats, such as pdf, but nothing has worked.

Interestingly enough, zooming in on the blurry sections seems to give some insight into what is happening:
[image: fuzzy zoom]

Each point appears to be aligned to connect to its neighbors, but the actual joining isn't going smoothly at all.  I assume this is an artifact of using the "group = 1" parameter to prevent ggplot from connecting all of the like-colored regions together.  However, I can't change that option for exactly that reason.

Is there a workaround to this issue that I could implement, or am I just running up against limitations of ggplot at this point?

Comment: Can't replicate. https://imgur.com/a/GwF5XXd  Can you post results of `sessionInfo()`? I've got R Under development (unstable) (2022-01-09 r81462); Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit); Running under: Pop!_OS 21.04; ggplot 3.3.5

Comment: Yes, part of the way it looks on OP's zoomed in view will depend on the viewport settings if in R studio, the image viewer being used if in file format, and size and resolution settings when saving the image.  That being said, see the suggested action that can probably address some of the graphical issue here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This has to do with having so many data points and a (relatively) thick line - so no issue with your plot code.  If you check your data using a smaller value for `size`, you don't get the "fuzzy" look, but it's harder to visualize the thin line:

```
ggplot(testData, aes(X, Y, color = Color, group=1)) +
  geom_path(size=0.5) + scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

The fix is to use the `lineend=...` argument in `geom_path()` to smooth out the places where the points are joined.  This does not have much effect at all until the line size is set to be pretty large (say, larger than 1).  The default value is `lineend="butt"` which draws a hard edge ending right at the point.  The option you want to use here is `lineend="round"` which gives a rounded edge.  Here's what it looks like:

```
ggplot(testData, aes(X, Y, color = Color, group=1)) +
  geom_path(size=1.5, lineend = "round") + scale_color_identity()
```

[image]

#### Detailed view of how it's working

To get a better idea why this works, let's take an example dataset shown below.  First, here's the plot when the default value is used (`lineend="butt"`):

```
set.seed(8675309)
df <- data.frame(x=1:20, y=sample(-50:50, size=20, replace=T), col = sample(LETTERS[1:2], size=20, replace=T))

ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=col, group=1)) +
  geom_path(size=5, lineend="butt", alpha=0.8, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Now here's the difference when you set `lineend="round"`:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x,y, color=col, group=1)) +
  geom_path(size=5, lineend="round", alpha=0.8, show.legend = FALSE) +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Many, many thanks!  I could have sworn I'd tried fiddling around with the lineend and linejoin parameters, but I clearly wasn't thorough enough.  Your description and the accompanying images are extremely helpful.  I greatly appreciate it!